# Codeception with Gherkin keywords in German

Tags: cucumber, bdd, codeception, gherkin

How can I configure Codeception to use Gherkin keywords in German?

[I know that this is possible in Cucumber.](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Spoken-languages)

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks as if Codeception supports the standard Gherkin syntax for language declaration [in the first line](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/pull/3203) of the scenario file:

```
#language: de
```

The list of [Gherkin-supported keywords](https://docs.cucumber.io/gherkin/reference/) is too big to list here, but includes these used for simple scenarios:

```
Feature - Funktionalität
Scenario - Szenario
Given - Angenommen / Gegeben Sei / Gegeben Seien
When - Wenn
Then - Dann
And - Und
But - Aber
```